# Add level picker in goolge map android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to show multilevel building if I am in a multi building in Google map android.Google map return any method or any custom method to show on map .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this line in onMapReady in your activity .

googleMap.getUiSettings().setIndoorLevelPickerEnabled(true);